# confused with 'prototype' (Firefox extension)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm developing a firefox extension and I think I've now hit a basic misunderstanding regarding Javascript, with the 'prototype' concept to be exact. Consider the following minimal example, notice the differences when I set the variables this.demo and this.test:

```
  var Example = new Array();

  Example.Foo = function() {
    this.test = null;
    this.demo = "World";
  };

  Example.Foo.prototype = {

    initialize : function(resource) {
      this.test = "Hello";
      this.display();
    },

    display : function() {
      alert(this.test + " " + this.demo);
    },
  }

  window.addEventListener(
    "load", 
    function() {
      window.obj = new Example.Foo();
      obj.initialize();
    }, 
    false
  );
```

When opening Firefox I get the expected output:

```
  Hello World
```

This works always fine this way as long as a call display() 'within' the js source file. However, when I call display() via corresponding click from a menu entry, e.g.:

```
...
    <menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup">
      <menuitem label="Example" oncommand="obj.display();"/>
    </menupopup>
...
```

I get:

```
  null World
```

initialize() has been called beforehand, of course.

I'm still rather new to Javascript and work with existing code. I'm therefore quite confused with the current behavior. What is the best solutions to get is working?

Comment: Check out these two articles: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml and http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm - your code is kind of all over the place. One thing that will help a lot, I think, is to not use the name `example` for both your definition and instance; it is more confusing when half your code is dealing with "example" this and "example" that. Get some real terms in there - it will help you think things through.

Comment: If you check what object `this` is when being calling from the menuitem, I think you will find that it's the menuitem and not the object that you expected.

Comment: btw, Arrays are for when the keys are integers. In this case use objects: `Example = {}`. (Also, even when you need an array you should use `[]` instead of new Array.

Answer (score 2):

Because `this` is referencing to the object that call the method.

```
var MyObject= new function(){

    this.value="Hello World!";

    this.display=function(){
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

<input type="button" value="Foo Bar!" onclick="MyObject.display()"> //Foo Bar!
```

this exemple will alert "Foo Bar!" instead of "Hello World!"

to prevent this unexpected situations you can add a "Checkpoint" using `var that=this;`

```
var MyObject= new function(){

    var that=this; // <--- reference to actual object

    this.value="Hello World";

    this.display=function(){
        alert(that.value);
    }

}

<input type="button" value="Foo Bar!" onclick="MyObject.display()"> //Hello World!
```

this will alert "Hello World!" 'value' from the MyObject not the 'value' of the  tag.

.

maybe this other situation help you to understand

```
<img scr="dog.gif" title="Little Dog" onclick="alert('This is a '+this.title)">
```

"This is a Little Dog"

Answer (score 0):

After many more hours, I solved my problem...somehow, I haven't fully understood so far.

Firstly, minimal example actually works. I've got the strange behavior because I integrated the lines of the example code into the application code. However, "deep down" in the code an error occurred which clashed with the call of initialize(). When I put the example code lines before the application code I always get the output `"Hello World"` (instead `"null World"` in one case)

Secondly, there was a fundamental flaw in the application. It's a Firefox extension featuring a Sidebar. With that `window.addEventListener(...)` is called twice, once for the sidebar, once for the "normal" browser window. I therefore had two separate `window.obj`. And the code calls `initialize()` only for the sidebar one. In 99% that was not an issues since most code uses the sidebar `window.obj`. The call from the context menu, however, targets the browser `window.obj`. As a solution I changed the the code in such a way that only the sidebar `window.obj` is used.

Sorry for looking in the wrong direction. Thanks a lot for all answers though. Your comments brought be back on the right track and definitely kept me motivated! :)

Christian